# One array of object pulls data while other doesn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

So I have the following `array of objects` as shown below:

```
const default_apps = [
    {
    'post_title': 'Excel',
    }, {
    'post_title': 'Word',
    }, {
    'post_title': 'SharePoint',
}];
console.log(default_apps);

const test = get_array_of_post_objects('application_launcher');
console.log(test);
```

Here is the console log for both, the top is `default_apps` and the bottom is `test`:
[image]

**Please note**: Both array of objects have `post_title: "..."` defined inside.

Could someone tell me when I call my vue app using the `default_apps` array of objects, I get a return as shown below:
[image]

But if I substitute `default_apps.map` for `test.map`, I get an empty array back as shown here:
[image]

They're both very similar array of objects, so I'm just a little confused - All help would be appreciated!

```
new Vue({
    name: 'o365-edit-modal-wrapper',
    el: '#o365-modal-edit-wrapper',
    data: function() {
        return {
            available_list: [],
            selected_list: default_apps.map((name, index) => {
                return {
                    name: name.post_title,
                    order: index + 1,
                    fixed: false
                };
            }),
            editable: true,
            isDragging: false,
            delayedDragging: false,
        }
    },
});
```

Here is the `get_array_of_objects` function if anyone wants to check it out:

```
function get_array_of_post_objects(slug)
{
    let items = [];
    wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
        const Posts = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
            url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/' + slug,
        });
        const all_posts = new Posts();
        all_posts.fetch().then((posts) => {
            items.push(...posts.items);
        });
    });
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**get_array_of_post_objects** function call is asynchronous call when executed it returns items which is an empty array and then when promise is resolved, no where to return it again, so you need to wait for the promise (resolved) to return the items.

Comment: Would I be able to somehow update my function or how would you take a approach on this if you don't mind me asking? I feel like I've tried everything but can't come up with a good answer.